# why does not .htaccess file work on the following website sak.ps?

Tags: .htaccess

I search for a way to hide php extension to show website files as folders and I found it can be done using .htaccessm and i found this code :

```
   RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But it does not working for me! 
Van anyone help please?

rewrite mode is enabled on server

Comment: The rule itself is fine. Maybe .htaccess files are disabled/ignored for performance/security purposes? If you place some other directives in .htaccess do you see them working?

Answer (score 1):

The website uses nginx which does not support Apache .htaccess files.

See https://serverfault.com/questions/24243/nginx-support-for-htaccess-rewrite-rules-differences-from-apache

Comment: how did you know the website uses nginx?

Comment: HTTP response headers (though these can be "doctored")